# import opencv with anaconda using python package

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I'm currently working on a project with anaconda. I was able to install opencv-python with the regular pip3 install (not anacondas version). When I import cv2, its successful.

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Oct  8 2020, 12:12:24) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>>
```

If I copy that package into my anaconda path, and run python with anaconda, import cv2 I get the following error:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Is there a way to get around this without using the Anacondas pip install? I don't have internet on the machine I'm working on. I've done this method with other packages and it has worked fine, not with opencv.

Comment: [.whl](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#files) << without internet ,you can download *.whl offline library to install (pip install xxxx.whl)

Comment: opencv have additional environment parameter setting, you can not only copy package

Comment: You solution worked for me in Windows, but I had to use the same version of Python, and the same version of NumPy (I see your are using Python 3.6.9 and Python 3.7.3).